# Clojure: determine if a function exists

Tags: clojure, lisp

how can i know if a function name provided as string is callable or not in the current context? something like:

```
(callable? "asdasd") ;; false
(callable? "filter") ;; true
```

thanks

Comment: Also note the word "callable" is being overloaded here. All Clojure functions are java.util.concurrent.Callables.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for resolve,

```
(resolve (symbol "asd"))
```

returns nil

```
(resolve (symbol "filter"))
```

return #'clojure.core/filter

To check if a var is a function (credit goes to @amalloy):

```
(-> s symbol resolve deref ifn?)
```

Comment: it returns what you said, but how can i determine if it is callable or not?

Comment: You can call (fn? (resolve (symbol "filter"))) - I'd recommend this over my answer

Comment: @JoostDiepenmaat: in this case `(fn? (eval (symbol "filter")))` - `resolve` returns class or var, not something with `Fn` interface (see my answer) and thus won't work.

Comment: @ffriend, just deref the var: `(when-let [f (resolve (symbol "filter"))] (and (var? f) (fn? @f)))`

Comment: @Justin Kramer: @Joost used `eval` in his answer, so I proposed it. Of course, dereferring is more idiomatic way for Clojure.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be doing this at all, but a whole solution is `(-> s symbol resolve deref ifn?)`.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are if you need this, you're doing something wrong, but...

```
(defn callable? 
  [s] 
  (let [obj (try (eval (symbol s)) (catch Exception e))]
  (and obj (fn? obj))))
```

Comment: Augh no. Using `resolve` is a sign you might be doing something wrong; using `eval` to do the same task is a sure sign you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
(defn callable? [name]      
   (clojure.test/function? (symbol name)))
```

**UPD.** I found out that `fn?` checks only for interface `Fn` and doesn't work for resolved symbol. Though, `clojure.test/function?` does what is needed, so I updated an example.